# Linux pc not starting. Giving a black screen with the writing below

Tags: linux, boot

[image: this is the screen I am getting when starting pc]

This is going on happening even after I switch off and on the pc... please help

Comment: It looks like your USB mouse does not have a good connection, although that might be masking some other problem. Try replacing or disconnecting the mouse, or plugging it to a different USB port.

Comment: The error you see on the screen is very unlikely to be the culprit.